# Python equivalent of chartR

Tags: python, replace

Life is so easy with the `chartr()` (R) function:

```
txtdata = "my têxt is plaîn of accent"
chartr("îêéè", "ieee", txtdata)
```

return `"my text is plan of accent"`

In Python the `re.sub()` function takes only one replacement value on the second arg:

```
re.sub("[éè]", "e", txtdata)
```

Is there a Python equivalent function to chartr() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `str.translate` is better suited to a task like this given the accent translation.

```
out = "my têxt is plaîn of accent".translate(str.maketrans("îêéè", "ieee"))
print(out)
'my text is plain of accent'
```

---

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.05 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def chartr(to_replace=None,to_replace_by=None,text=None):
      if len(to_replace) == len(to_replace_by):
            to_replace = list(to_replace)
            to_replace_by = list(to_replace_by)
            for i in range(0,len(to_replace)):
                  text = re.sub(to_replace[i], to_replace_by[i], text)
            return(text)
      else:
            return("length must be the same")
chartr("éeàâäî","eeaaai",body)
```